# How do you align cards in a row format using semantic ui React after using the map() function

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

When you hard code the cards it works well and they in row format, but when i try to iterate through them using the map function, it doesn't work. please help me.

```
  const BodyComponent = (props) => {

    const [ restaurants, setRestaurants ] = useState([
      {name: "Rolex Guy Entebbe", },
      {name: "Cafe Java Victoria Mall", },
      {name: "KFC Vicatoria Mall", },
      {name: "Niki's Pizzeria", },
      {name: "muti Restaurant", },
    ])

    return(
      <Container style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}>
        <div>
          {
            restaurants.map(restaurant => 
            <Card.Group itemsPerRow={4} stackable>
              <CardComponent />
            </Card.Group>
            )
          }       
        </div>
      </Container>
    )
  }

  export default BodyComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, it looks like you want to `map` `Card` and not `Card.Group`:

```
return(
      <Container style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}>
        <div>
            <Card.Group itemsPerRow={4} stackable>
            {
              restaurants.map(restaurant => 
                <CardComponent />
              )
            }  
            </Card.Group>     
        </div>
      </Container>
);
```

You also would need (most likely) pass some props to `CardComponent`:

```
<CardComponent restaurant={restaurant} />
```

Comment: Am rendering the CardComponent that i created in a separate component file, that i want to pass down the props to.

Comment: Yes, this should work.  Do you have a question about how do pass props?